# Semi-global variable to mclapply

Tags: r, mclapply

In a function, I need to run `mclapply` per each item in a list and it should also use a semi-global variable `var.1`. I don't want to add `var.1` to every list-item as it would take too much memory. Here is code that illustrate the problem:

```
library(parallel)

list.1 <- list(1,2,3,4)

myInnerFunction <- function(xx) {
  return(xx+var.1)
}

myOuterFunction <- function(list.x) {
  var.1 <- 17
  tmp.1 <- mclapply(list.x, myInnerFunction, mc.cores=6)
  return(tmp.1)
}

results <- myOuterFunction(list.x=list.1)
[1] "Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : object 'var.1' not found\n"
results[[1]] # This should be 18
```

How can I pass `var.1` to `mclapply`? `var.1` must be declared inside `myOuterFunction`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a second (`var.1`) argument for the function `myInnerFunction`:

```
myInnerFunction <- function(xx, var.1) {
  return(xx+var.1)
}
```

Now it is possible to pass the second argument for the `myInnerFunction` function in the `mclapply` command:

```
myOuterFunction <- function(list.x) {
  var.1 <- 17
  tmp.1 <- mclapply(list.x, myInnerFunction, var.1, mc.cores=6)
  return(tmp.1)
}
```

The result:

```
results <- myOuterFunction(list.x=list.1)


[[1]]
[1] 18

[[2]]
[1] 19

[[3]]
[1] 20

[[4]]
[1] 21
```

Answer (score 2):

Does a function closure do want you want?

Create a function `f`, that takes in `var.1` as an argument, and returns `myInnerFunction`

```
f = function(var.1) {
    var.1 = var.1
    myInnerFunction <- function(xx)  return(xx+var.1)
}
```

Then `myOuterFunction` is:

```
myOuterFunction <- function(list.x) {
    var.1 <- 17
    my = f(var.1)
    tmp.1 <- mclapply(list.x, my, mc.cores=6)
    return(tmp.1)
}
```

and

```
myOuterFunction(list.x=list.1)
```

works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Useful info, I didn't know this. The answer from Sven turned out to be most practical in my specific case.